# "Unable to load the requested file" 

Tags: php, codeigniter

Using CodeIgniter 2.0.3 on XAMPP 1.7.7 I have code where I get the error as: `Unable to load the requested file: home.php`

The `home.php` code as follows stored in `./ci2/application/controllers`:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

    function Home()
    {
        parent::__construct();   
    }

    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

While using it just notice:

1. controller's name is *home.php*
2. File named *home.php* must be present in **ci/views**
3. Incase file extention in view folder is not php eg like its html.
   then load it using : `$this->load->view('home.html');`
4. the function u need to call from outside must be public So make it:
   `public function index() {... }`

as u are calling the constructor for the class Home. Call it like:

```
class Home extends CI_Controller {

function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();   
}

public function index()
{
    $this->load->view('home');
}
```

Now it will work !

Answer (score 0):

Your call to `$this->load->view('home');` will be looking for `home.php` in `/ci2/application/views/`. That's the file it can't find.

I'm assuming you're calling http://myapp/index.php/home/ - that means it'll automatically call the `index()` method.

Comment: so if $this->load->controllers('home') will look in the correct place T or F? I want the home.php to load at this adddrss http://localhost/ci2/

Comment: I am trying to get ci2 to display my customised home page.

Comment: http://teachitshem.blogspot.com/2011/01/firing-up-codeigniter-over-xampp.html this is the url where the original source code was initially found later was modified.

Comment: What view have you created for your home page? On the page you linked to, they use `$this->load->view('home_view');` and he has created a file in the `/application/views/` directory named `home_view.php` - you need to do the same (call that file `home.php` as that's what you're trying to load)

Comment: Thank you Simon. transcripting error somehow something made me ignore the "_view". :/

Answer (score -2):

```
class Home extends CI_Controller
{
    function __construct()
    {
        parent::__construct();   
    }
    function index()
    {
        $this->load->view('home');
    }   
}
```

Please check the name of the file you have created in application/views/, because otherwise the code is correct.